# ArcMap 10.3 interoperability; can't get WFS to display the right set of polygons based on my search envelope

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, wfs, data-interoperability

I have a [public WFS](https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/bag/wfs?request=GetCapabilities), from which I want to make a selection to save in a custom feature class.

I have made an interoperability connection, chosen the right feature classes to display, set the maximum number of features to 60 000 and set a search envelope. However, the connection doesn't display the polygons from the right area, but only the area around it (seems like). Also, despite setting a feature limit of 60 000, only 15 000 features are loaded. [screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEX82.jpg)

As expected, Esri's online help is not a help at all.

I don't have the interoperability extension, just using what's there in stock ArcMap.

Comment: Any logs, what arcgis sends and what you receive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer here was pretty simple: the WFS provider chose to set a limit to the number of features requested, which was at 15000, so that's why I wasn't able to get more than that.

Still there's something buggy in ESRI's conveyance of the WFS as I got features from outside the search envelope. However, after contacting UK ESRI support, they told me you HAVE to tick the *clip to search envelope* box, otherwise it won't work properly. This sounded to me as a bug, but they assured me it is a feature.